# SSRS Recursive Hierarchy when parent is also child

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a recursive hierarchy showing managers and employee salary by department.  The problem I have is that the manager can have a salary, but also have child employees reporting to them.
How it's coming out in SSRS is like this:

**Employee         Salary**
Manager 1            $350,000
   Employee 1         $50,000
   Employee 2         $50,000
   Manager 2          $150,000
      Employee 3         $50,000

Where the manager is earning $100,000.  So, basically SSRS is rolling up to the manager level, which I want, but it's not breaking out the manager to be a separate row as well, so the report is confusing.

Thanks so much!

Mike.

Comment: Share sample data and expected results in order to help you. At a glance I think you have wrong grouping settings.

Comment: If I had to do this, I would look into changing my SQL so that there are two Manager rows, one in which he is a child of himself, just like his employees.   That row would show his individual salary, and the Parent row would roll them all up in a subtotal.